# PowerShell - Office365 Calendar REST API v1.0: Search by Subject

Tags: rest, powershell, office365, office365api

I am trying to use PowerShell to query a group calendar and return only a subset of the events based on a specific string in the Subject field.

Currently, I can use the following and get a listing of all of the events:

```
$events = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/$calendar/calendarview?startDateTime=$(Get-Date)&endDateTime=$((Get-Date).AddDays(1))" -Credential $cred | foreach-object{$_.Value}

$events | Select-Object -Property Subject,Start,End | fl
```

This is where I get stuck. I am trying to filter these results to where I only return results where `Subject -like '*string*'`

However, I just cannot seem to get that to work on the `Invoke-RestMethod` line...

Any help would be GREATLY appreaciated.

Bonus appreciation to anyone who can take the results of the Start and Stop times from this:

> 2016-04-25T13:00:00Z

to this:

> 4/25/2016

For reference, I have already tried this:

```
Get-Date $events.Start -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'
```

Which gives this error:

> Get-Date : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'System.DateTime' required by parameter 'Date'. Specified method is
>   not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your using a CalendarView (which is a filter of sorts) you can't apply another filter at the REST level so just filter the results eg

```
$events | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match 'string'} | Select-Object -Property Subject,Start,End | fl
```

or if you want to use wildcards

```
$events | Where-Object {$_.Subject -Like '*string*'} | Select-Object -Property Subject,Start,End | fl
```

With the Start Stop time just CAST them eg

```
$events | % {([DateTime]$_.Start).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: epic sir. Thank you!